# How to extract only the desired text using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, nlp

So I have list of Tibetan words with their POS tag as shown below:

```
ད་གདོད DET
ད་གཟོད PART
ད་ཏྲིག NO_POS
ད་དུང PART
ད་དྲག NOUN
```

How can I strip out these POS tags and output only the below:

```
ད་གདོད
ད་གཟོད
ད་ཏྲིག 
ད་དུང 
ད་དྲག
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x.split(" ")[0] for x in list_]
```

returns

```
['ད་གདོད', 'ད་གཟོད', 'ད་ཏྲིག', 'ད་དུང', 'ད་དྲག']
```

if you want printing then this:

```
for x in list_:
    print(x.split(" ")[0])
```

prints out:

```
ད་གདོད
ད་གཟོད
ད་ཏྲིག
ད་དུང
ད་དྲག
```